# Install Firefox Addon from a link, instead of downloading the .xpi

Tags: firefox-addon

I just made a FF addon and made a simple website. I'd like when a visitor clicks the  "download" button the addon to install, instead of getting downloaded. It works locally, but not when I upload the site. I checked the mozilla repository, they just link to the xpi file as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if mozilla gives special treatment to repository urls. After all, you wouldn't want every random site on the web to be able to initiate add-on installation in the browser just by serving up a file.

Comment: I have seen other sites where I can just click and install an addon. Also, it works locally.

Comment: then check the mimetype that's being served up from the repository and stuff that into your system as well.

Comment: Don't know what's a mimetype :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't registered the XPI MIME type for your website. You can do this by adding the following rule to your site's `.htaccess` file (assuming your site uses an Apache server):

```
AddType application/x-xpinstall .xpi
```

This should result in what you want (a user clicks the link and is prompted to install the XPI file).

Fore More Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Extension_Packaging#Making_an_extension_XPI

Comment: Thanks. I found this helpful. If you're using IIS and asp.net MVC, this is done by `<mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall" />` inside  `staticContent` inside web.config.

Comment: Still works as of Oct 2019 (Many other answers on stackexchange for this question are outdated)

Comment: Is there a solution in the case that the XPI is stored on a server I have no influence on?