# How to Allow a User to Install FireFox Extension from My Website

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I just had a FireFox extension approved in the Mozilla Add-On directory, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to allow a user to install the extension from my website.

In other words, I'm trying to prevent directing the user to my extensions listing on the Mozilla Add-On directory and would rather just have them be able to install the extension from my website.

Google Chrome Add-ons allow for this functionality (they call it "inline installation" and it can be read about here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation)

Is this kind of functionality possible with FireFox Add-Ons that are listed & approved in the Mozilla Add-On Directory?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Extension_Packaging See "Making an extension XPI"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307742/install-firefox-addon-from-a-link-instead-of-downloading-the-xpi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Installing Extensions and Themes From Web Pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages)

Comment: This page does not (no longer?) talks about inline installation.

Comment: That page currently talks about `InstallTrigger`, which is [currently documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InstallTrigger) as being nonstandard.

Comment: @Brian any updated on the Installer? Is there any standard/updated version yet?

Comment: @Rahatur: I don't know.  For unlisted extensions, I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/a/15379337/18192 .  For listed extensions, I don't know of an officially supported way to provide inline installation.  You may be better off asking for advice on the Mozilla forums.

Answer (score 1):

You can put link to this extension on your site with information, that user should/have to install it.

```
<a href="http://www.somepage.com/addons/yourAddon.xpi">You need plugin</a>
```

If you don't have something like that in your web.config:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".xpi" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall" />
</staticContent>
```

firefox will download addon instead of install.

Comment: This approach does work, but it is generally only appropriate for unlisted extensions.